# Limit of a function in terms of nearness.

Tags: general-topology, limits, analysis

The following paragraph is quoted from [this Wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function).

> At the 1908 international congress of mathematics F. Riesz introduced an alternate way defining limits and continuity in concept called "nearness". A point $x$ is defined to be *near* a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ if for every $r>0$ there is a point $a\in A$ so that $|x-a|<r$. In this setting the $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$ if and only if for all $A\subset\mathbb R$, $L$ is near $f(A)$ whenever $a$ is near $A$. Here $f(A)$ is the set $\{f(x)|x\in A\}$. This definition can also be extended to metric and topological spaces.

Let me rewrite the definition of nearness in a topological space $X$. A point $x\in X$ is said to be near a set $A\subset X$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at some point $a$.

Now isn’t this just $x\in\overline{A}$?

So Wiki has claimed the following nice characterization for  limit of a function:

> $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if for every $A\subset\mathbb R$, $a\in\overline{A}$ implies that $L\in\overline{f(A)}$.

Does this statement really hold? Why can’t wiki just use the term “closure” rather than defining the notion of “nearness” separately?

Comment: That Wiki section is very inadequate and ahistorical. For a more complete and accurate discussion, see [*Frigyes Riesz and the emergence of general topology*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00407-014-0144-6) by Laura Rodríguez (2015). Unfortunately, I don't believe this is freely available online.

Answer (score 1):

> A point $x\in X$ is said to be near a set $A\subset X$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at some point $a$.
>   Now isn’t this just $x\in\overline{A}$?

Yes.

> $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if for every $A\subset\mathbb R$, $a\in\overline{A}$ implies that $L\in\overline{f(A)}$.
>   Does this statement really hold?

Yes. (I assume that $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to a topological space).

Both answers are easy to check.